# where should i put my owl file in order to loadable via python owlready

Tags: python, pycharm, ontology, owlready

I'm being in final project of my study. I analyze public conversation about governor election in twitter by mention and hashtag. And then I make an ontology from its result.
The ontology I make manually with protege and wish to run this protege OWL file with python.
According to [this link](http://pythonhosted.org/Owlready/onto.html#loading-an-ontology-from-owl), we can load local copy of the OWL file

```
>>> onto = onto_path.append("/path/to/owlready/onto/")
```

I tried similar line of above code like this

```
>>> onto = onto_path.append("E:/dir/dir/ontologyfile.owl")
>>> onto.load()
```

but the error shows up, said that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'`. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

From [Loading an ontology from OWL files](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/onto.html#loading-an-ontology-from-owl-files):

> If an URL is given, Owlready2 first searches for a local copy of the
>   OWL file and, if not found, tries to download it from the Internet.

This works for me on Windows:

```python
>>> from owlready import *
>>> onto = get_ontology("file://E:/dir/dir/ontologyfile.owl")
>>> onto.load()
```

As well as this:

```python
>>> from owlready import *
>>> onto_path.append("E:/dir/dir/")
>>> onto = get_ontology("http://absulutelyrandomdomain.com/ontologyfile.owl")
>>> onto.load()
```

Comment: what about owl:imports? they are loaded only from the web??? I want a special version that is stored locally in the same folder. How to do this?